# Jquery .on or .click function only works for first for mysql echo rows

Tags: php, jquery

Solved in comment Thanks :)

I tried many different versions like .click and .on but it only works for the first button and nothing else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#RedeemCodeDiv").on("click", "button#delete", function() {
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```

and here is my PHP which is being echoed by how any results there are which prints out the values and everything looks fine it's just when I click on the second delete code button nothing happens

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["status"]=="open") {
        echo('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="RedeemCodeDiv">
            Redeem Code: <strong>'.$row["RedeemCode"].'</strong>
            Status: <strong>'.$row["status"].'</strong>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="delete" value='.$row["id"].'>Delete Code <span id="loader"></span></button>
        </div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: use class instead of ID. `ID should be unique` it will only get one element. change `$("#RedeemCodeDiv").on("click", "button#delete", function() {` to `$(document).on("click", "button.delete", function() {` bind your element to `document` since your `RedeemCodeDiv` is also dynamically added.

Comment: use class intead.

Comment: @guradio Thanks for helping me understand my issue it is now resolved :)

Comment: @JacobWebb glad it works i will add it as answer so we can close the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use class instead of ID.
2. `ID should be unique in context`.
3. Change `$("#RedeemCodeDiv").on("click", "button#delete", function() {` to `$(document).on("click", "button.delete", function() {`
4. Bind your element to `document` since your element `RedeemCodeDiv` is also
   dynamically added.